# Error DataImportHandler with Oracle Database (Apache Solr)

Tags: java, xml, database, oracle, solr

When I try to import all the docs (binarys sources) of the Oracle Database in the solr project, the log show me this error:

```
 Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Could not load driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver Processing Document # 1
```

I tried to fix that but I not find any answers

Comment: did you have the lib file at right path? the path should be /solr-6.1.0/server/lib and the jar is ojdbc6.jar

Comment: once add the lib , please restart the server

Comment: also check the spelling mentioned in the data-config.xml driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"

Comment: thanks Abhijit, Its works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check the path for the `"ojdbc6.jar"` file, it should be `"/solr-6.1.0/server/lib"`
2. check the spelling mentioned in the `data-config.xml` `driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"`

Please restart the Solr server.